# How can I make Vim open .py files in different lines?

Tags: python, vim, spyder

Previously, I used Spyder to write my files, but recently began making the transition to Vim. When I open a .py file using Vim, all previous lines are blended into the first, but separated with **^M**.

My *~/.vimrc* file uses **filetype plugin indent on** which I thought would solve this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file that has only `^M` (also known as `<CR>`, or carriage return) as line separator is using the file format of `mac`. That seems to be the format of the file you're opening here.

Since this file format is so unusual, Vim will not try to detect it. You can tell Vim to detect it by adding the following to your vimrc file:

```
set file formats+=mac
```

Alternatively, you can use this format while opening a single file by using:

```
:e ++ff=mac script.py
```

You might want to convert these files to the more normal `unix` file format. You can do so after opening a file, with:

```
:set ff=unix
```

And then saving the file, with `:w` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know `^M` is the special character used for carriage return in vim. You should just be able to replace it

`:%s/^M/\r/g`

I would imagine that the ^M is there as some kind of specific configuration spider uses that couldn't be translated well in vim. I am just speculating here, could be totally wrong.

Comment: I feel like you could be on the right track, but the ^M's are greyed out, making them undetectable by the command.

Comment: The way to match a `^M` character on the pattern side is `\r`, so this should be `:%s/\r/\r/g`, which should work as expected. Note that this looks odd, but it's correct. `\r` means different things on the pattern and replacement sides. It matches a carriage return (`^M`) on the pattern, but produces an actual newline on the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting using hexadecimal notation is better in my opinion:

```
:%s/\%x0D$//e
```

Explanation: If the user try to type caret M instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> he of she will think that is a mistake.